What is the Fourier Transform of an Ideal Smoothed Particle Fluid?
I've had some adventures with Fourier Transforms (FT) in the past. Me and FT go back a long way and we see each other on a regular basis. And now I'm trying to introduce FT to a new friend I've made along the way, the Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics (SPH). Let me tell you all about it so we can help them get along.
SPH is a Lagrangian grid-free approach to computational fluid simulation. I won't go into the details of why the methodology works but one key aspect of SPH is that the fluid is represented as a set of fluid parcels centered at particular points, each of which have a certain "influence radius". The value of the fluid's mass density at each point in the simulation space is given by the sum of the influence of each parcel acting on that point. We can express that idea like so
$$
\label{sph-main}
\tag{1}
\rho(\vec x) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} m_i W(|\vec x - \vec R_i|)
$$
Here $m_i$ is the mass of fluid represented by the $i$-th particle and the function $W$ is called a kernel function. I think it can be non-spherical but all my experience with the method relates to spherically symetrical kernels, so we're sticking with those. Overall most of the computational details can be savoured slowly in this video for those who want to chew on the computational side of things. Visually, we can think of the SPH fluid representation as a series of overlapping bubbles:

All of which combine to give one continuous seamless fluid:

If there are enough bubbles, and they are small enough, then your fluid will be as continuous as it gets. Think a bung of Styrofoam pellets rolling off a box, how much fluid-like they look. About that much.
So let's talk about kernel functions, the $W$ in the equation \eqref{sph-main}. They can have many functional forms and often are chosen to have compact support in the radial domain so as to avoid costly computations of pairwise interactions between far-away parcels. This helps accelerate the computation of the thing. However most theorems and strategies and identities I have come accross while skimming (yes, that is the word, sadly) SPH theory are discovered and identified using gaussian functions as the ideal kernel. Then, these results are shamelessly ported to other kernels and somehow everything works out. Computers, heh? Can't math with them, can't math without them.
Anyways, while playing around with FT and SPH I came accross an an interesting result. Suppose I have a gaussian kernel $W(r) = \exp (-\alpha r^2)$. Its FT, according to Wolfram Alpha, is shown in Equation \eqref{gaussian-kernel-FT-original}:
$$
\label{gaussian-kernel-FT-original}
\tag{2}
\mathcal{F} [\exp (-\alpha r^2)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\alpha}}\exp \left(-\frac{\hat{r}^2}{4\alpha} \right)
$$
If we make the substituion that $\frac{1}{4\alpha}=\beta$ then we can write
$$
\label{gaussian-kernel-FT}
\tag{3}
\mathcal{F} [\exp (-\alpha r^2)] = \sqrt{\beta} \exp \left(-\beta{\hat{r}^2}\right)
$$
Which look a lot like another gaussian function, but this time in the reciprocal space, rather than the real space. And seeing as how $\beta$ is the reciprocal of $\alpha$, this means that the wider a kernel is in real space, the narrower it'll be in reciprocal space. Like so:

This got me thinking. If the FT of a gaussian is a gaussian, and since the ideal SPH fluids are just a sum of gaussian kernels, then could I perhaps represent the FT of an SPH fluid as an SPH fluid in reciprocal space? Is that a thing?
Now that I have an expression for the FT of the ideal kernel, in order to complete my recipocal SPH fluid I would need a way to decide what are the values for $\hat u$ and $\hat v$, the coordinates of each parcel in reciprocal space, given the coordinates of each parcel in real space. Because if the fluid parcel is this:

Then there could perhaps be an equivalent (or maybe more than one?) fluid parcel in reciprocal spacel like so:

I don't know whether these ideas are even remotely rigorous or whether they apply at all. I am not a professional mathematician myself, I'm just a curious dabbler and occasional user of numerical results. But thinking this through really got me going on this, so now I am very curious as to end result of this entire journey. Seeing as I wasn't able to come up with anything conclusive on this matter, I hereby post the question to you, sages of the Stack Exchange:
Is there a way to find the reciprocal SPH representation of an SPH fluid by figuring out where to place the parcels in reciprocal space?
That is, given each parcel centered at $\{(u,v)\}$ in real space can we find the equivalent reciprocal parcels centered at $\{(\hat u, \hat v)\}$ in reciprocal space and be confident that this is the true FT of an ideal SPH fluid? Is that a thing that can be done? Is there an algorithm to do it? So many doubts, so little time...

FT is unique and associative. So if you find the FT of each particle modeled as a gaussian and sum them up, that will be the FT of the collection and will be unique

I don't think the reciprocal parcel coordinates $(\hat{u}, \hat{v})$ exist. Instead, the FT of your SPH density will consist of a collection of Gaussians, all of which are centered at the origin. Instead of a unique offset in Fourier space for each Gaussian, each one will be multiplied by a unique plane wave depending upon the position of the original parcel: $\exp(-i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{R}_i)$, where $\vec{q} = (\hat{u}, \hat{v})$.
